# Use multiple fonts with tailwind and set default one in next 13.4.19

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

Stack:

```
"tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
"next": "13.4.19",
"@next/font": "^13.4.19"
```

I'am using multiple fonts:

```
import { Poppins, Titillium_Web } from 'next/font/google';

const sans = Titillium_Web({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  weight: ['400', '700'],
  variable: '--font-titillium',
});

const mono = Poppins({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  weight: ['400', '700'],
  variable: '--font-poppins',
});
```

injected like this:

```
<body id="home-body" className={`${sans.variable} ${mono.variable}`}>
  {children}
</body
```

and then in tailwind.config.js:

```
fontFamily: {
        sans: ['var(--font-sans)', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
        mono: ['var(--font-mono)']
}
```

issues is that `sans` is not applied by default however both fonts work if i set them explicitly `font-sans` || `font-mono`

how to set font-sans to default one?